# How to get the logs from IDE terminal

Tags: javascript, automation, console, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I want to check mixpanel events, so for this I intercept request with wanted url and I want after specific lines of code assert that right thing was printed in the console

Here is my code:

```
browser
  .captureNetworkRequests((requestParams) => {
    if (requestParams.request.method === 'POST' && requestParams.request.url === tEventUrl) {
      const postData = requestParams.request.postData;
      const dataObject = JSON.parse(postData);
      console.log('t Event: ', dataObject.event);
    }
  });
```

So during the code some t Events are triggered and sent, I just want to assert that their text matches what I expect.

Or maybe there is some other way to assert it without checking the terminal output

I found nightwatch getLog method, but from what I see it reacts to the browser console, not the one in my IDE